# How do I put the php variable into css

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I would like to have a dynamic style color base on the database

```
// the first line is static
$row_color = $value['late'] >= 60 ? ' style="color:red;"' : '';$

// and this code is not working
$color = $value['color'];
$row_color = $value['status'] == "OT" ? ' style="color: $color"' : '';
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your correct them first.

Comment: You can add this directly in your html code

Comment: I dont get any error . on the second and third line . but the color is not changing

Comment: `<?php echo $color ; ?>` this is not required you can direct write `$color`

Comment: color = $value['color']; should be $color = $value['color']; 

You must use variable starting with $ in PHP.And use without echo inside the sting if not used inside HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put php in css file. What you can do is you can create two different classes in your .css file, and in php page you can load those classes depending on the condition.

e.g. file.css may have

```
.color-red { color: red; }
.color-blue { color: blue; }
```

in file.php you can put

```
$color = ($value['late'] >= 60) ? 'color-red' : 'color-blue';
```

in your html tag you can use it like

```
<div class="<?php echo $color?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to concate $color here

```
$color = $value['color'];
$row_color = $value['status'] == "OT" ? 'style="color:'.$color.';"' : '';
```

if you are passing this to view then just do

```
$color = $value['color'];
$data['row_color'] = $value['status'] == "OT" ? 'style="color:'.$color.';"' : '';
```

And pass this $data to view and use it as variable line i.e

```
<div <?php echo $row_color; ?> ></div>
<span <?php echo $row_color; ?> ></span>
```

Comment: The echo shouldn't be inside `class`. That's read `<div class="style="color:#f00""></div>`. Just do `<div <?php echo $row_color ?>>`.